# Showing sequence has upper bound

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm working on this Proposition:

Let p stand for a sequence of reals from 0 to infinity.
Let L = limit as k goes to infinity of p-sub-k.

If the sequence p is non-decreasing then p-sub-k <= L for all k>=0.

This Proposition has been giving me grief for too long. It seems as though I could use the much more common and easier approach in first proving that if a sequence converges then it is bounded and therefore it has an upper bound and thus showing that L is the least upper bound is pretty easy given the completeness axiom.

However, the numbering of the Propositions in the course has that Proposition for all convergent sequences being bounded after the Proposition that I've cited above so it would be out of order to use it. It also seems to me that I'm missing some more obvious solution since the proof's concept is easy to grasp.

Any amount of help would be appreciated thanks. On a side, this is my first post so if there are any suggestions you guys have to make my question asking more productive for the both of us let me know!

Comment: @Nameless That only proves the statement for all $k>N$ where $N$ is the smallest you get over all $\epsilon$. There could still be an element early in the sequence which violates the condition.

Comment: @NotNotLogical, you are right, I neglected the earlier terms. Thank you for that.

Comment: @Nameless You're solution is much simpler though. I think it could by salvaged by arguing that the early terms must be less than the later terms.

Comment: @NotNotLogical, you have me wrapped in your fingers now...as the terms are *nondecreasing*, I suppose so. But let's wait for OP to respond.

Comment: @Nameless As I think about it though, I'm not sure again. We would have to establish that there exists an element actually _less than or equal $L$_, whereas that argument only shows there's an element arbitrarily close to - but perhaps greater than - $L$. If you find a way to make it work, I would like to see it, maybe post as a second answer and tag me in a comment to let me know... cheers!

Comment: There is an element? It's for every $k > N$. I am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toward a contradiction, suppose that there exists a $k$ such that $p_k>L$ where $L=\lim_{k\to\infty}p_k$. Then, because $p_k$ is monotone non-decreasing, we must have $$p_x\ge p_k>L$$ for all $x>k$. This means that all terms after the $k$'th are greater than $L$ by at least $p_k-L>0$.

But if this is true, consider the limit of $p_k$. We should have that for $\epsilon>0$, and hence for the particular $$\epsilon=p_k-L>0$$ we can find an $N$ such that $k>N$ implies $|p_k-L|<\epsilon$. But as per the inequality above, $$|p_x-L|=p_x-L>p_k-L$$ for all $x>k$. Therefore we *cannot* make $$|p_x-L|<p_k-L$$ for all $x$ greater than some $N$, contradicting the definition of the limit.

Thus there is no $k$ such that $p_k>L$, and the sequence is bounded above by $L$.

We can say more than this, however. Not only is the sequence bounded, but $L$ is its *least* upper bound - I leave the proof to the reader :)

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks for the help! I can't believe I haven't arrived at this, I've been trying to draw out a contradiction for so long!

Comment: @user136150 Glad I could help :)